# "no valid OpenPGP data found" error installing Docker

Tags: software-installation, docker, gnupg

Help me to install Docker:

```
spyam@linux:~$ curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403 
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

This is on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
wget https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg
apt-key add gpg
```

I just downloaded the key with no issue.

Comment: again error : spyam@linux:~$ sudo apt-key add gpg
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.

Comment: Maybe the docker people has a problem with the key file right at this moment?

Comment: My dear friend, I don't know what the solution is to solve this problem.

Comment: I have no problem downloading the key.

Comment: My friends, I downloaded it and wanted to install it offline. I got an error again. What is the solution?